# What does double initialization mean in Java methods

Tags: java, initialization

I only use double initialization in java for classes 
ex:`new ArrayList(){{add()}}` 
But I recently wrote a code as below by mistake and JVM did not get angry for my mistake.

```
public void test(){
    {
        {
            ....
        }
    }
}
```

After that made a simple example and saw the following but still didn' t understand anything expect order of running statements.

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        HelloWorld hw=new HelloWorld();
        hw.test1();
        System.out.println("----------");
        hw.test2();
     }

    public void test1(){
        {
            {
                System.out.println("1");
            }
            System.out.println("2");
        }
        System.out.println("3");
    }

    public void test2(){
        System.out.println("a");
        {
            System.out.println("b");
            {
                System.out.println("c");
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Result:

```
1
2
3
----------
a
b
c
```

So my question is that what does double or triple etc initializations mean in Java?

Comment: You should strongly consider not using double-brace initialization at all. It is a deceptive syntactic fudge that opens you up to all sorts of problems, such as serializable bugs, memory leaks etc. If you want an ArrayList with given elements, use `new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("your", "elements"))`.

Answer (score 4):

This is not double brace initilization. This is a block statement. From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html):

> A block is a group of zero or more statements between balanced braces and can be used anywhere a single statement is allowed.

A block statement encloses the statements within it in a different scope. So if you did:

```
public static int foo() {
    {
        int foo = 0;
    }
    return foo;
}
```

`foo` would not be in scope in the line `return foo;` and you would get an error

---

In your code, these nested blocks make no difference, as you are just printing, but each block will have a different scope

Comment: **thanks.** @gblodgett. But still didn' t understant why is this exists. When could this code block be usefull?

Comment: @demdem If you think about it, `if` statements, `while` loops, `for` loops, etc, all execute a statement or *block*. Usually a block is used in tandem with these constructs, but it is legal to use them without